# market filter for memory class

Tags: android, memory, filter, google-play

Is there any way to hide apps in the android market for devices that fall in a certain memory class? eg. i only want to release the app for devices that have memory class 32 or higher( AcivityManager.getMemoryClass() ).

The <uses-configuration> tag only has screen / keyboard related flags, and <uses-feature> also has no memory related settings.

Is there any other way to specify necessary device attributes for an app?

Comment: I'm curious what solution you came up with (if any), as I am in the very same boat. We track every bitmap and recycle ASAP, but the content of our app is simply too large for certain devices to manage. We're currently using the new device based filter on the Play console along with other little tricks, like checking nativeHeapSize constantly in an attempt to fail gracefully, avoiding dreaded OutOfMemory errors, but would much prefer simply to declare a minimum RAM requirement as desktop software products have for around 2 decades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the AndroidManifest documentation and there is nothing that says anything about memory. The Market filters work with the information in the AndroidManifest, so I think it's not possible.

The only think I can think of is selecting devices in the Google Play console that are allowed to download it. But that requires a lot of manually selecting the correct devices.

Maybe you can request it as a feature with Google?